# MongoDB $lookup (aggregation) and $project based on performance

Tags: mongodb

Hey all i was doing some performance tests on large aggregation mongo scripts and I noticed when I move the project line from

```html
  

           "$lookup":{
        "from": "metrics",
        "as":   "metrics",
        "let": {"userId": "$_id"},
        "pipeline": {
        {"$match":{"$expr": {"$in": {"$$userId","$ownerIds"}}}},
  ----> {"$project": {"fieldName": 1, "ownerIds": 1, "auth0Cache": 1}},
},
},
```

to

```html
      "$lookup":{
        "from": "metrics",
        "as":   "metrics",
        "let": {"userId": "$_id"},
        "pipeline": {
---->   {"$project": {"fieldName": 1, "ownerIds": 1, "auth0Cache": 1}},
        {"$match":{"$expr": {"$in": {"$$userId","$ownerIds"}}}},
     
},
},
```

It made performance jump. It ran 2-3times faster. It kinda makes sense that when you limit the data since this collection is a big one it should run faster, but I didn't find any documentation about it. Does anyone know why this is an important change and can explain to me why exactly is happening and provide some more information about it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to post this question in official MongoDB community forum as well: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/

Comment: Please also show us the explain output with executionStats flag.

Answer (score 0):

There is too little information in the question currently to draw any definitive conclusions. As [@Tornike Skhulukhia suggests in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74150870/mongodb-lookup-aggregation-and-project-based-on-performance#comment130923134_74150870), sharing the full `.explain("executionStats")` output for this aggregation would give us much more visibility into what may be happening.

One thing that looks potentially suspicious here based on the little that has been shared is the use of curly brackets (`{` and `}`) to define the `pipeline`. Normally that is an array to allow for a sequence of aggregation stages to be provided. Indeed [mongoplayground complains when curly brackets are used](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nDtC7HZyvTL). This is probably just a copy/paste error when creating the question, especially since there is the same typo with the `$in` list, but certainly if the driver/language you are using collapsed the `pipeline` down to just the first stage that may help explain what is happening. Note that it *is* possible in some situations to pass a single document (representing the sole aggregation stage) to the `.aggregate()` method itself rather than an array as usual, [here is a small playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-MGE4GmXCg9) proving that such structure runs successfully there. So shenanigans along these lines are not out of the question and more information would be helpful.

If I read between the lines a little bit, it sounds like you are trying to improve performance of some aggregation pipeline. While, again, there is not enough information to say anything for sure, I would suggest simplifying the definition of this `$lookup`.  Your existing stage is defined as follows:

```
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "metrics",
      "as": "metrics",
      "let": {
        "userId": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$$userId",
                "$ownerIds"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "fieldName": 1,
            "ownerIds": 1,
            "auth0Cache": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  }
```

This can be simplified to use the `localField`/`foreignField` syntax at least as follows:

```
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "metrics",
      "as": "metrics",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "ownerIds",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "fieldName": 1,
            "ownerIds": 1,
            "auth0Cache": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  }
```

Playground demonstrations of [before](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rrR9GEsbyX9) and [after](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ShjmPCgqayf).

This change may allow the database to better leverage an index of `{ ownerIds: 1 }` on the `metrics` collection.

The final thing that I'd mention is related to usage of `$project`. It is true to say that it is generally a good idea to reduce the amount of data being processed as early as possible. But usage of projection should be reserved for the end of a pipeline (or subpipeline) just as a means for transforming the results into the format that you desire. The database will automatically take care of figuring out what fields are needed by the pipeline and will optimally limit that data whenever possible.

Comment: Hey I created a in mongodb forum as well there I posted the explain and the full aggregation here : https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/lookup-aggregation-and-project-based-on-performance/194959/3